# SQL Select Distinct Top 2

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

If I have a table named [Part] with columns [PartID],[IDNumber], and [Length] and data:

```
[PartID]  [IDNumber]  [Length]
1         Test1       50
2         Test1       60
3         Test2       50
4         Test3       70
```

How can I select just the top 2 records with a distinct IDNumber? After searching for a bit I have not been able to find a query that does what I want. I would like the results to look like this:

```
[PartID]  [IDNumber]  [Length]
1         Test1       50
3         Test2       50
```

What I have now:

```
Select distinct top 2
        [PartID],
        [IDNumber],
        [Length]
from
    [Part]
```

To clarify that the PartID is actually a GUID. I thought writing out the GUID for each record was getting a bit messing in my example data.

Comment: Top 2 by what?  **There is no default ordering in SQL.**

Comment: So you want the TOP 2 groups (by [IDNumber]) as ordered  by PartId then from both of these 2 groups you want the single top record?

Comment: Top 2 ordering by `PartID ASC`?

Comment: @Lamak The order does not matter to much in this so ordering by the PartID is fine. @Martin Yeah I think that describes it pretty well. I only need two records and each record must have a distinct IDNumber.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 PartId, IdNumber, Length
FROM
(   SELECT PartId, IdNumber, Length, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by IdNumber order by Length) Orden
    FROM [Ayuda]
) A
WHERE A.Orden = 1
ORDER BY Length
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT TOP 2 b.* 
FROM   (SELECT idnumber, 
               MIN(partid) partid 
        FROM   part 
        GROUP  BY idnumber) a 
       JOIN part b 
         ON a.partid = b.partid  
ORDER  BY b.partid
```

Comment: +1 Wonder if there's a way of doing it with just a single partial scan though.

Comment: @Martin - Now that the op added that he's using SQL Server 2005, maybe he can try @Longha 's answer and see if that avoids one extra scan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to clarify but my PartID field is actually a GUID. Sorry about that. When I was typing the sample data I thought is was a bit messy to write out the whole GUID.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned which row to select for duplicate IDNumber. From your example, assuming Min PartID is to be used, you can use the following query. It would need to be tweaked a bit.

```
Select Top 2
    P.*
From
    [Part] P
Inner Join
    (
        Select
             [IDNumber]
            ,Min([PartID]) As MinPartID,
        From
            [Part]
        Group By
            [IDNumber]
    ) T
On
    P.PartID = T.MinPartID
    And
    P.IDNumber = T.IDNumber -- May not be needed is PartID is primary Key
Order By
     P.[PartID]
    ,P.[IDNumber]
```