# Maximum number of records that can hold by a DataGridView in WIndowsForms Application

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wonder what is the maximum number of rows a DataGridView which is bind to a database can render ? I want to know this because I have a table of about 1050 rows but it's shows me only the half of records (525 rows), I don't know why?!
Is there any limit on maximum  of records datagridview in C# .net Windows application ? I have search and searched 2 days but  don't find any solution to solve this issue.

Code that fills the DataGridView:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct * from BLC", conx); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
sda.Fill(dt); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Probably you have an error in your code that queries the database. 1050 rows are not a limiting factor for a DataGridView

Comment: what may be the error ?

Comment: And how do I know? At least you should post the code that creates your query and executes it

Comment: Well, you are requesting the DISTINCT set of rows from your table, this means that a row that is an exact duplicate of another row is discarded from the returned result set. This could explain the 525 rows against 1050. If you execute the same query with Sql Server Management Studio what is the count of rows returned with and without the DISTINCT keyword?

Comment: BY the way, next time press the [edit] button to update your question without posting many lines of code in a comment where they are unreadable

Comment: @Steve ok sorry
when i use the Distinct in sql server management it returns 525 rows and the same result if not but to show all the records (1050) i've did Select Top 1050 so i tried to do it in my query of the code but it doesn't work

Comment: @Y.Arsoy Use ORDER to use TOP with DISTINCT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503692/sql-select-distinct-top-2

Comment: @Steve oh,Thanks
you saved my life